# First hour in first date - DAX power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to figure out what happened first.
our agents calling a customer or the customer making a deposit freely then only later an agent called

I start by comparing the first date then time of the phone calls Vs. the first date then time of the transactions

I immediately got stuck trying to get the first call hour of the first call date

[image]

If I make a calculated column in the Dim accounts table of a simple Min(PhoneCalls[Hour]) then i get a 9.

I want to get a 15. that is the first hour of the first date.

any ideas??

Comment: Please provide the sample data in a [table format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow) and provide a desired output based on the data.

Answer (score 1):

You get a 9 because 9 is the minimum value of the entire column. DAX needs to see that you want the minimum value by [celldate].
SUMMARIZE will provide a list of all distinct values in the column. Then you can name and write an expression (i.e. MIN('table'[Hour])) grouped by that summarized list of dates.

I don't have data to test this out, but it should look something like this:

```
SUMMARIZE('table','table'[calldate],"first",MIN('table'[Hour]))
```

Comment: ^Made an edit because I forgot to put MIN() into expression argument

Comment: right, so this kinda works because it gives me the first date and the first hour (i added a top 1)
but how to i turn this into a scalar in order to compare it to the other face trade?

Comment: 'compare it to the other face trade?' - I'm not sure I follow. May you edit your question and provide an example of your desired output at the bottom?